# Hide id param in url in Grails App

Tags: url, grails, url-mapping

I have a URL that looks like **/myController/myAction/id**.

How could I hide the id in that URL so it looks like:  **/myController/myAction/username [email]**

Comment: Obscurity is not security

Answer (score 2):

Define in UrlMapping.groovy as `"/myController/myAction/$username"(controller: "myController",action: "myAction")` and you'll be able to get the param in controller `params.username`

Answer (score 0):

Define in `UrlMapping.groovy` as `"/myController/myAction/$username"(controller: "myController",action: "myAction")`

you'll be able to get the param in controller `params.username`