# want to hide id parameter from url in grails

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, url-mapping

I have a URL that looks like `/myController/myAction/id`.

How could I hide the id in that URL so it looks like: `/myController/myAction/username`
and still recieve id in controller

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16838160/hide-id-param-in-url-in-grails-app

Comment: also see my comment on the question

Answer (score 0):

If you are not actually sending Id in any other way and send only username and can get user by username and still need to have user.id in controller. As @Mr.Cat mentioned in a given link by @Alidad:
`"/myController/myAction/$username"(controller: "myController",action: "myAction")`
then add filter:

```
class userFilters {
    def filters = {
        addId(controller: 'myController', action: 'myAction') {
            before = {
                if (params && params.username) {
                    def u = User.findByUsername(params.username)
                    params.id = u.id
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```